# Plugin not reloading in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am having a weird problem with a plugin I wrote. What is weird is that I have one other plugin that opens various ActiveRecord classes and it has no problems auto-reloading.

In the plugins init.rb file I have

```
User.class_eval do
  has_one :reputation
  include Karma 
  alias :rep :reputation
end
```

If I run it in production mode or in rails console there are no issues. When I run it in development it does load it once, but never again unless I restart the server.

I couldn't find anything special in the other plugin I am using(acts_as_readable) and it opens User in the same manner.

---

Edit:

I did:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  class << self
    def has_karma_values
      has_one :reputation
      alias :rep :reputation
    end
  end
end
```

in the plugiin's init.rb file and did

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_karma_values
...
end
```

And get the same error about has_karma_values not existing. The plugin hasn't been loaded at this point.

What is confusing is that acts-as-readable has no issues at all with

```
User.class_eval do
  has_many :readings
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActiveRecord::Acts::Readable
```

but yet mine does.

Here is my complete init.rb file

```
require 'reputation'
require 'karma_name'
require 'karma_tag'
require 'karma_title'
require 'acts_as_karmable'
require 'karma'
require File.expand_path('../lib/generators/karma_generator', __FILE__)

KarmaTitle.setup 'Default'

ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  class << self
    def has_karma_values
      has_one :reputation
      alias :rep :reputation
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActiveRecord::Acts::Karmable
```

Here is the error `/home/david/apps/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1014:in`method_missing': undefined local variable or method `has_karma_values' for #<Class:0x9ad1b24> (NameError)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
# plugin init.rb
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  User.class_eval do
    has_one :reputation
    include Karma 
    alias :rep :reputation
  end
end
```

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem, thank you. Is this going to cause redundant loading in production? I would still love to know why acts_as_readable doesn't need this little hack. Very strange inconsistency.

Comment: `#to_prepare` is called in development at the beginning of each request/response cycle, and in production only once, immediately after initialization.

Answer (score 3):

The init file is loaded once, you should not access your models from your plugin, it should be the other way around, your init file should probably be like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  class << self 
    def acts_as_readable
      has_one :reputation
      include Karma
      alias :rep :reputation
    end
  end
end
```

And at your user.rb file you should do it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_readable
end
```

And this should give you the functionality you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I couldn't get it to work, it has the same errors as before. I added the details as an edit in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for giving me another way of looking at the problem.